# Validate 2 different types of input for a Textbox

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox, user-input

I have a textbox named (txtColor) and a button.

Under this button click event, there are 2 validate events, in which the user is forced to type numbers only or type with no restrictions.

Can I get some guide on how to go about this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: There is no "validate event". There's a `Validating` event and the handler for that is where you do your validation. When the user tries to shift focus, that event is raised. If validation fails, you set `e.Cancel` to `True` and the control will refuse to lose focus. You can also call `ValidateChildren` on the form to validate every control, including those that have never received focus.

Comment: As for the validation itself, you can kill two birds with one stone by calling `Integer.TryParse` or `Double.TryParse`. An empty `String` won't parse to a number so that case is covered as well as input that is not numerical. If you did need to check two different conditions though, you simply use `AndAlso` in your `If` statement. You really ought to understand something about Boolean logic BEFORE you start programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a button to do this, you need checkbox
when checkbox is checked, textbox accept numbers only, while if not, it accepts everything

under your textbox (txtColor) KeyPress event paste this code:

```
if checkbox1.checked = true then
e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
end if
```

and it is done